# Reliably synchronising SDL animation with VSYNC in windowed mode

Tags: opengl, windows, sdl2

I have an SDL/OpenGL program which creates a rendering context with `PRESENTVSYNC` enabled, then enters an animation loop which calls `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` each time around. On my own machine, the animation works fine at a sensible speed, but on my office machine it runs with no vsync delay at all resulting in the animation running at breakneck speed and tearing all over the frame. Adding a sleep() to the animation loop slows it down sensibly.

I know that I can use `SDL_GL_GetSwapInterval` to see if swapping is being synchronized or not, but is there a way to find out what the actual refresh rate of the screen is in order to know how long or short the sleep should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval). Pass in 1 to enable VSYNC.

`SDL_PRESENT_VSYNC` is a `SDL_Renderer` flag and has no effect on pure OpenGL rendering. It only affects rendering performed using the SDL's rendering module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SDL_GetDisplayMode` or `SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode`, which will copy data into an `SDL_DisplayMode` you pass it, including the screen's refresh rate.

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDisplayMode